# Homebrew: How install disabled package(php7.1)?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I try to install **php7.1** (via command **brew install php@7.1**) for my work-project on my new macbook, but i got following message:

```
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I can't reject using php7.1 because it requirement of my work.

How can I install **php7.1** on **MacOS**?

Comment: I had to face this problem for more than 2 months. And I am failed to solve this problem. It's a really sad thing. Please go to this [blog](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-upgrade-mac) You can definitely update your Php version.

Comment: Upgrade with **shivammathur/homebrew-php**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by making sure brew is up-to-date:

```
brew update
```

Normal upgrade

```
brew upgrade PHP
```

Normal upgrade does not work in many macOS old Versions.

Upgrade with shivammathur/homebrew-php

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.1
```

To switch between versions, use the following command:

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1
```

Next steps

Check the current version by running `php -v`:

If you can then, `Restart Nginx or Apache` also:

refer [Link](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-upgrade-mac)

Comment: In this case, you've provided a location from which to install the older formula, but this answer would be more robust if your steps included guidance for finding such a formula.